# Template substitution with whitelist support?

Tags: python, string, templates

Is it possible to use `string.Template` to **mandatorily** replace a set of variables mentioned in **whitelist** (`$placeholder*`) **and** skip the rest (`$data` etc.)?

`substitute` throws an exception for all non-existent placeholders; `safe_substitute` ignores all non-existent placeholders -- so is there something in between?

```
from string import Template

whitelist = {"placeholder1", "placeholder2", "placeholder3", "placeholder4"}

query = Template("select * from t where c1= $data and c1 = $placeholder1 and c2 = $placeholder2")

print(query.safe_substitute({"placeholder1": "c1"}))  # Not safe.

query.substitute({"placeholder1": "c1"})  # Extra safe.
```

I can do this validation, at the end, by looping through the *whitelist*, but that seems *inefficient*. Also, I don't see a support for this in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Lib/string.py#L104-L121).

---

If there are no good solutions, can I sub-class `Template` and over-ride `substitute` like this:

```
def substitute(self, mapping=_sentinel_dict, /, **kws, whitelist):
    if mapping is _sentinel_dict:
        mapping = kws
    elif kws:
        mapping = _ChainMap(kws, mapping)
    # Helper function for .sub()
    def convert(mo):
        # Check the most common path first.
        named = mo.group('named') or mo.group('braced')
        if named is not None:
            # ====> Suggested change. <====
            if named in whitelist:
                return str(mapping[named])
            else:
                return mo.group()  # ====> Taken from safe_substitute.
        if mo.group('escaped') is not None:
            return self.delimiter
        if mo.group('invalid') is not None:
            self._invalid(mo)
        raise ValueError('Unrecognized named group in pattern',
                         self.pattern)
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your proposed implementation is *almost* perfect.

- First of all, be aware that this implementation does not allow you to do things like `MyTemplate('$whitelist').substitute(whitelist='a')` and get `'a'` as a result (because you can't pass multiple values for argument `whitelist`).
- Then, you need to change `if named in whitelist: return str(mapping[named])` into something slightly more complex. Indeed, in that way you are not handling correctly the case in which `named` is not in `whitelist` but is part of `mapping`. Therefore, you need to do something like

```
if named in mapping:
    return str(mapping[named])
if named in whitelist:
    raise KeyError(named)
```

Here is a working implementation:

```
from collections import ChainMap
from string import Template

class MyTemplate(Template):
    def substitute(self, mapping=None, whitelist=None, **kws):
        mapping = kws if mapping is None else ChainMap(kws, mapping)
        whitelist = {} if whitelist is None else whitelist
        def convert(mo):
            named = mo.group('named') or mo.group('braced')
            if named is not None:
                if named in mapping:
                    return str(mapping[named])
                if named in whitelist:
                    raise KeyError(named)
                return mo.group()
            if mo.group('escaped') is not None:
                return self.delimiter
            if mo.group('invalid') is not None:
                self._invalid(mo)
            raise ValueError('Unrecognized named group in pattern', self.pattern)
        return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
```

And here are some examples:

```
>>> whitelist = {'a', 'b'}
>>> temp = MyTemplate('Lorem $a $b sit ${c}')
>>> temp.substitute({'a': 'ipsum', 'b': 'dolor', 'c': 'amet'}, whitelist)
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
>>> temp.substitute({'a': 'ipsum', 'b': 'dolor'}, whitelist)
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ${c}'
>>> temp.substitute({'a': 'ipsum', 'c': 'amet'})
'Lorem ipsum $b sit amet'
>>> temp.substitute({'a': 'ipsum', 'c': 'amet'}, whitelist)
...
KeyError: 'b'
```

The advantage of subclassing `Template` (instead of implementing another solution) is that the subclass comes with all the other features of `Template` (for example, you can change the delimiter '$' to something else, or you can define your own rules to identify a placeholder, etc).

Comment: I was thinking of keeping `whitelist` as a global `set` variable (or per Template), but then changed it to an argument while submitting the question. I'll have a closer look. Thanks!

Comment: @Nishant One option is to pass it to MyTemplate when you create it, but then you need to create a new template object every time you want to change `whitelist`. It really depends on your needs, like is `whitelist` constant or does it change over time?

Comment: It is a constant unless there is a business change :-)